# Multiple Ubuntu installation in one HD

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I'm trying to install three Ubuntu OSes (same version) in one hard drive for experimental purposes. Only these OSes will be installed. Using virtualization is not an option due to some requirements in experimentation.

So I'm trying to set it up this way: 1 boot partition, 1 swap partition, and 3 partitions for the independent Ubuntu OSes. I don't need a shared root partition since they will all be independent of each other.  I haven't checked if this setup works since I'm setting up in our PC lab and have yet to go back.

Questions:
1. Will this HD partitioning work? If not, what is the recommended partitioning?

2. How can they be set up for multiboot? Won't they have any problems in booting up since they will try to install their grub in the same path?

Thank you.

Comment: 1. Silly idea. Get rid of the boot partition. 2. Sure, you'll need to tell two of them to install Grub to their respective partitions.